# How can I achieve this blacklisting of properties based on Property Type with Utf8Json?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

**Goal**

Based on a `Type` and `string` representing the parent class and property respectively, I want to filter properties on serialization.

I'm aware that Utf8Json (and Newtonsoft for that matter) support attributes on the field but due to the codebase I'd like to do it based on defined blacklists stored in dictionaries.

**Already working example with Newtonsoft**

At the moment with the `Newtonsoft.Json` package I have similar to the following code (cut down for brevity).

```
public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public Dictionary<Type, string> SerializeBlackList { get; set; }

    public ShouldSerializeContractResolver()
    {
        SerializeBlackList = new Dictionary<Type, string> {
            { typeof(Shape), "ShapePropertyFoo" },
            { typeof(Shape), "ShapePropertyBar" },
        };
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        if (SerializeBlackList == null || SerializeBlackList?.ContainsKey(type) == false)
        {
            return base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        }

        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        return properties.Where(p => SerializeBlackList[type] != p.PropertyName).ToList();
    }
}
```

Later instantiated, stored in a variable and serialization is called.

```
var fooSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        ContractResolver = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver()
                    });
var resultString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results, Formatting.None, fooSettings);
```

Comment: In .Net Core 3.0.0 this seems not to be implemented.  1) [`JsonClassInfo`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonClassInfo.cs) and [`JsonPropertyInfo`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonPropertyInfo.cs) - the equivalents to `JsonContract` - are **internal**.

Comment: 2) There is no support for the `ShouldSerializeXXX()` pattern.  If there were it would be somewhere in [`JsonSerializer.Write.HandleObject.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Write.HandleObject.cs#L68) -- but it's not.

Comment: See: [Equivalent of DefaultContractResolver in System.Text.Json #42001](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/42001).  As a workaround you could add a converter that replaces blacklisted type(s) with `null`, or an empty object.